# What did the rose mean?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 6 episode 7 of Game of Thrones

> Queen Margaery secretly passed a note with a drawing of a rose to her grandmother

What did the rose mean?

> clearly it means that she is in it for the long game and is not really a true follower

but was it also some reference to an earlier moment?

Comment: I believe it was just supposed to be a sign of "hey, not brainwashed, it's still me in here, so when I'm telling you to leave the city, I really mean you need to leave the city".

Comment: I agree. It was just a message that "Still a Tyrell, Still growing strong".

Comment: It's their sigil.

Comment: [You sure it was a rose?](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CkSa2dgXAAAidIr.jpg:large)

Answer (score 14):

The Rose is the symbol of [House Tyrell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Tyrell).

> Their sigil is a golden rose on a green field, and their words are "Growing Strong."

As you mentioned this is a signal to the Queen of Thorns that Margaery is not completely brainwashed. Margaery is telling her grandmother "listen to me, please".

She probably used the house sigil as it was easy to fit on a small scrap of parchment and would convey the needed message. Also, if the note was found it would be easier to deny any true meaning.

Answer (score 4):

On its own, the rose is not terribly meaningful. It is a sigil of their house, and, at most, an indicator that she was still part of it - nothing especially deviant. If she presented it overtly, it would probably mean very little.

The reason it *did* mean something has less to do with the rose itself, and more with her passing it in secret. Her willingness to hide something from the Faith was the real sign that she does not belong to them.

Answer (score 0):

Well apart from Rose being the sigil of their house with motto Growing strong, I have a theory that I am using to pacify my curiosity.

In a discussion High Septon asked Margaery if she was doing her duty to be of service to the king in bed and this is what the God's would expect. Plus her attonement was canceled and instead she's proclaimed as a representative of Faith in their wedlock.

So maybe she's indicating of Growing Strong with a child inside her already or indicating to have one soon and may pounce back with some wicked plan as soon as she has a chance...

Comment: Interesting. The rose may have also signified her need for "moon tea". However I find this highly unlikely for two reasons: **1.** She would be leaving this tiny clue which is a huge gamble on whether or not her Grandmother would realise; and **2.** It's *way* too deep and complicated for the GoT viewers to understand.

Comment: @Möoz Unlikely to be about moon tea, a 'baby in the belly' would cement her position and is basically the most important thing she could do.  Until she'd birthed an heir, she could be put aside for another queen given adequate pretext.